# How to join 2 different table which does not have any link

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to join 2 different table which does not have any link

Table 1 - Stock on hand (has all the item of the store)

Table 2 - Sales

Now I need data from Table 1 and Table 2 in one file
Table 1

```
ItemCode SOH_Quantity
aaaaaaaa 10
bbbbbbbb 12
cccccccc 20
```

Table 2

```
ItemCode Quantity InvoiceNo Date
aaaaaaaa 1        001       25/01/2021
```

I need below output

```
ItemCode Quantity Type
aaaaaaaa 10        I
bbbbbbbb 12        I 
cccccccc 20        I
aaaaaaaa 1         S
```

please help me to fetch the expected output

Answer (score 2):

What you described is not a "join", it is a "union".

Use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT
    ItemCode
    ,SOH_Quantity AS Quantity
    ,'I' AS Type
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    ItemCode
    ,Quantity
    ,'S' AS Type
FROM Table2
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with `UNION`

```
SELECT ItemCode, SOH_Quantity as Quantity, 'I' AS TYPE
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ItemCode, Quantity, 'S' AS TYPE
FROM table2
```

Comment: `union all` was unnecessary as the type column was going to prevent duplicate rows in the first place. The benefit is that the query plan will not need to ensure that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like, basically it's an UNION (like an addition of rows) of two tables, not a JOIN:

```
    SELECT ItemCode, SOH_Quantity AS Quantity, 'I' as Type FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ItemCode, Quantity, 'S' AS Type FROM Table2
```

Note how we made sure that we fetch the same column names from both tables for this to work.